# Is there a way to loop through multiple range variables after using Find to determine them in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

After finding in which cells the VBreed2, VHoog2, and VLang2 data are, I need to loop through them to see which ones are not empty, followed by figuring if they are all the same. I have yet to find a way to loop through several variables like that, so does anyone know how to do that?

This is what I have so far, but it will eventually get expanded with help of the value for i.

```
Private Sub AfmInv()
Dim A_rng As Range, a As Range
Set A_rng = Sheets("Result").Range("A1", Sheets("Result").Range("A1").End(xlRight))
Dim sku_r As Range, r As Range
Set sku_r = Sheets("Result").Range("A2", Sheets("Result").Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Dim VBreed1 As Range, VBreed2 As Range, VHoog1 As Range, VHoog2 As Range, VLang1 As Range, VLang2 As Range, VAfmeting As Range
Dim i As Long, i1 As Variant, i2 As Variant

With A_rng
    Set VBreed1 = .Find("breedte_verpakking", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set VBreed2 = .Find("breedte_verpakking-unit", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set VHoog1 = .Find("hoogte_verpakking", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set VHoog2 = .Find("hoogte_verpakking-unit", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set VLang1 = .Find("lengte_verpakking", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set VLang2 = .Find("lengte_verpakking-unit", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set VAfmeting = .Find("afmetingen_verpakking_totaal", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
End With

For Each r in sku_r
    Set VBreed2 = Sheets("Result").Cells(r.Row, VBreed2.Column)
    Set VHoog2 = Sheets("Result").Cells(r.Row, VHoog2.Column)
    Set VLang2 = Sheets("Result").Cells(r.Row, VLang2.Column)
    For Each a In ??? '(VBreed2, VHoog2, VLang2)
        If a.Value <> vbNullString Then
            If a.Value = "CENTIMETER" Then
            i1 = 1
            ElseIf a.Value = "MILLIMETER" Then
            i2 = 1
            Else
            i = 0
            End If
        End If
    Next a
    If i1 + i2 <> 1 Then
        i = 0
    Else
        i = 1
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: Perhaps `For Each a In union(VBreed2, VHoog2, VLang2)`, but not sure what you're doing. Won't you be overwriting `i, i1 and i2` each time? Also probably better practice not to re-use variable names. And when using `Find`, always check first that the item is found to avoid errors.

Comment: With the current set up it would indeed constantly get overwritten, but once I add the rest of the code before the `Next r` it works as intented. I was unaware of the union function and it seems like it will work for me, so thanks! I've also made seperate variables as you suggested for the `Find` functions.